# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when accessing BigDecimal initialized by valueof(0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, nosuchmethoderror

I have a class `User` with the BigDecimal field it's private and I'm trying to access it through getter.

But when I'm trying to access balance I get NoSuchMethodError

```
@Service
public class PaymentProcessor {

    @Autowired
    UserDaoService userDao;

    public void withdrawFunds(String payerId, double amount){
        User payer = userDao.getByUserName(payerId);
        if ( payer.getBalance().doubleValue()   // I get Error here
                < amount){
            throw new RuntimeException("Insufficient Funds");
        }
        else {
            payer.updateBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount * (-1)));
            userDao.saveUser(payer);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT USER CLASS ADDED

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private String personalInfo;
    private int rating;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
        userRoles.add(new UserRole("default"));
        this.rating = 0;
        this.balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    }

    public void updateBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = this.balance.add(balance);
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post your User class?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of `BigDecimal.valueOf(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your private variable to: `private BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;`

The error happens, because in this line `User payer = userDao.getByUserName(payerId);`, you are calling the default constructor from the `User` which has `balance` as null value

```
public class User() {
  super()
  .....
  this.balance = null;
  ....
}
```